# Resume training in Caffe from the previous training point

Tags: caffe

Im facing severe power cuts in my hometown,and i had to restart my training multiple times,any suggestions on how i can resume my training from my last iteration point?
I am using caffe,and lmdb files.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caffe can save a "snapshot" every once in a while. You can resume your training from the last snapshot you have by simply:

```
$CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools/caffe train -model /path/to/solver.prototxt -snapshot /path/to/latest.solverstate
```

In your `solver.prototxt` you can define how often a snapshot is taken by setting

```
snapshot: 2500  # take a snapshot every 2500 iterations
```

The snapshot file is saved to the same location defined by

```
snapshot_prefix: "/path/to/snaps"
```

There you can find both `.solverstate` and `.caffemodel` saved for each 2500 iterations.

Comment: Thanks for your time Shai,but i cant seem to find a .snapshot file,but i do have a solverstate and caffemodel file.

Comment: @Ryan my bad. it's ".solverstate" and not ".snapshot". please see my edit.

Comment: Im getting-                                                                                                   ` Cannot copy param 0 weights from layer 'conv10'; shape mismatch.  Source param shape is 7 512 1 1 (3584); target param shape is 6 512 1 1 (3072). To learn this layer's parameters from scratch rather than copying from a saved net, rename the layer.`

Comment: what layer am i supposed to rename?

Comment: @Ryan you are not suppose to change the net structure between snaps.

Comment: I havent changed anything yet

Comment: @Ryan it seems, from the error message you got, like you did make a change to the net (in layer `conv10`.

Comment: may be i messed up somewhere,thanks for the help!will let you know if problems occur when i resume training some other time.

Comment: I ran a 100 iterations just to check if i got it right, when i cancel the training and resume it giving it the 100_iter file,i get CudaSucess (2 vs 0 ) out of memory error-im not running any other model.

Comment: try `nvidia-smi` to see what else is on your GPU. It might be the case that the other process did not die and is just suspended.

Comment: I checked your related answer to the above question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790366/caffe-check-failed-error-cudasuccess-2-vs-0-out-of-memory),if i change the batch size at the moment-im worrie that i will be changing the net

Comment: @Ryan changing batch size should not affect your layer structure. It's a serious bug if it does.

Comment: I changed the batch size from 16 to 8- its working fine,thanks for the help

Comment: Kindly suggest something for this issue(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659270/trouble-training-caffe-model-cudnn-status-internal-error).

Comment: I added snapshot at 1022 iteration but it  just gets ignored and training starts from 0 iteration