# Caffe: What can I do if only a small batch fits into memory?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

I am trying to train a very large model. Therefore, I can only fit a very small batch size into GPU memory. Working with small batch sizes results with very [noisy gradient estimations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33717093/1714410).
What can I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/201775/66467

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change the `iter_size` in the solver parameters.
Caffe accumulates gradients over `iter_size` x `batch_size` instances in each stochastic gradient descent step.
So increasing `iter_size` can also get more stable gradient when you cannot use large batch_size due to the limited memory.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68323/choosing-an-appropriate-minibatch-size-for-stochastic-gradient-descent-sgd?rq=1), the batch size is not a problem in theory (the efficiency of stochastic gradient descent has been proven with a batch of size 1). Make sure you implement your batch correctly (the samples should be randomly picked over your data).

Comment: indeed it's a nice theoretical result, but in practice, especially when the net is large and involves many parameters, one might still prefer using larger batch size.

Comment: Can you provide a little more details about your implementation? Number of parameters? The maximum batch size you can use?

Comment: I am trying to learn a recurrent model: therefore, the batch size is a trade off between the number of time steps I can unroll and the number of independent sequences I can process. The more time steps I include, the fewer sequences I can process and thus the noise in the gradient estimation raises.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/192769/tricks-2012.pdf.