# Is it possible to use arbitrary image sizes in caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I know that caffe has the so called spatial pyramid layer, which enables networks to use arbitrary image sizes. The problem I have is, that the network seems to refuse, to use arbitrary image sizes within a single batch. Do I miss something or is this the real problem?.

My train_val.prototxt:

```
name: "digits"
layer {
  name: "input"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/Users/rvaldez/Documents/Datasets/Digits/SeperatedProviderV3_1020_batchnormalizedV2AndSPP/1/caffe/train_lmdb"
    batch_size: 64
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "input"
  type: "Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    scale: 0.00390625
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/Users/rvaldez/Documents/Datasets/Digits/SeperatedProviderV3_1020_batchnormalizedV2AndSPP/1/caffe/test_lmdb"
    batch_size: 10
    backend: LMDB
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 20
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "pool1"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "pool1"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "bn1"
  type: "BatchNorm"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "bn1"
  batch_norm_param {
    use_global_stats: false
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
}
layer {
  name: "bn1"
  type: "BatchNorm"
  bottom: "pool1"
  top: "bn1"
  batch_norm_param {
    use_global_stats: true
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "bn1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 50
    kernel_size: 5
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "spatial_pyramid_pooling"
  type: "SPP"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  spp_param {
    pyramid_height: 2
  }
} 
layer {
  name: "bn2"
  type: "BatchNorm"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "bn2"
  batch_norm_param {
    use_global_stats: false
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
}
layer {
  name: "bn2"
  type: "BatchNorm"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "bn2"
  batch_norm_param {
    use_global_stats: true
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 0
  }
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "ip1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "bn2"
  top: "ip1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 500
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip1"
}
layer {
  name: "ip2"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 10
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "ip2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "ip2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

---

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188136/using-the-spp-layer-in-caffe-results-in-check-failed-pad-w-kernel-w-1-vs) to another question regarding a subsequent problem.

Comment: i think it would be better if you resize them before training,an arbitrary will create confusing if you have pad and fiters defined,you can do that wilth opencv cv2.imresize(imgfile,(height,widht))

Comment: If I resize them, which benefit do I gain from using an spatial pyramid pooling layer? Does not make sense to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing several concepts here.

**Can a *net* accept arbitrary input shapes?**
Well, not all nets can work with any input shape. In many cases a net is restricted to the input shape for which it was trained.
In most cases, when using fully-connected layers (`"InnerProduct"`), these layers expects an *exact* input dimension, thus changing the input shape "breaks" these layers and restrict the net to a *specific*, pre-defined input shape.
On the other hand "fully convolutional nets" are more flexible with regard to input shape and can usually process any input shape.

**Can one change input shape during batch training?**
Even if your net architecture allows for arbitrary input shape, you cannot use whatever shape you want during *batch* training because the input shape of all samples in a single batch must be the same: How can you concatenate a 27x27 image with another of shape 17x17?

It seems like the error you are getting is from the `"Data"` layer that is struggling with concatenating samples of different shapes into a single batch.

You can resolve this issue by setting `batch_size: 1` processing one sample at a time and set [`iter_size: 32`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36532014/1714410) in your `solver.prototxt` to average the gradients over 32 samples getting the SGD effect of `batch_size: 32`.

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer, I did as you suggested and it solved the problem. I also ran into a subsequent problem, you may look into my edited question? Would be great! -  I will mark your answer as the correct one anyway :-)

Comment: @R_Valdez if you have a new question, you should *ask* a new question (consider link them for context).

Comment: Ok, I will ask a new question.

Comment: I asked another question. You can find the link in my edited question.