# how to use iter_size in caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

I dont know the exact meaning of `'iter_size'` in `caffe solver` though I googled a lot. [it always says that `'iter_size'` is a way to effectively increase the batch size without requiring the extra GPU memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36532014/1714410).

Could I understand it as this:

> If set bach_size=10,iter_size=10, its behavior is the same as
>   batch_size = 100.

But I do two tests on this:

> 1. total samples = 6. batch_size = 6, iter_size = 1, trainning samples and test samples are the same. the loss and accuracy graph :

[image: loss]

> 2. total samples = 6. batch_size = 1, iter_size = 6, trainning samples and test samples are the same.

[image: loss]

from this two tests, you can see that it behaves very differently.

So I misunderstood the true meaning of `'iter_size'`. But how can I do to get the behavior of gradient descent the same as over all samples rather than mini_batch?
Could anybody give me some help?

Comment: good question. I suspect `iter_size` might be used only for training and not for testing. Can you repeat the second experiment with `batch_size: 1` and `iter_size: 6` only for training and leave `batch_size: 6` for test? I would expect the train-test graphs to coincide after this change.

Comment: sorry for non-clarification about the parameters in the testing phase. For all the two experiments, batch_size is 6 in the testing phase,and test_iter is 1.The second experiment just conducted with batch_size:1 and iter_size:6. So I expect the two experiments should output the same loss and accuracy, but I was disappointed a lot@Shai