# Compute the number of epoch from iteration in training?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pytorch

I have a Caffe prototxt as follows:

```
stepsize: 20000
iter_size: 4
batch_size: 10
gamma =0.1
```

in which, the dataset has **40.000** images. It means after **20000** iters, the learning rate will decrease **10** times. In pytorch, I want to compute the number of the epoch to have the same behavior in caffe (for learning rate). How many epoch should I use to decrease learning rate 10 times (note that, we have **iter_size=4 and batch_size=10**). Thanks

Ref: [Epoch vs Iteration when training neural networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752626/epoch-vs-iteration-when-training-neural-networks)

My answer: Example: if you have **40000** training examples, and batch size is 10, then it will take **40000/10 =4000** iterations to complete 1 epoch. Hence, **20000** iters to reduce learning rate in caffe will same as **5** epochs in pytorch.

Answer (score 2):

You did not take into account [`iter_size: 4`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36526959/1714410): when batch is too large to fit into memory, you can "split" it into several iterations.
In your example, the actual batch size is `batch_size`x`iter_size`=10 * 4 = 40. Therefore, an epoch takes only 1,000 iterations and therefore you need to decrease the learning rate after 20 epochs.